# Error con relaciones uno muchos RestFul spring hibernate

Tags: api, spring, hibernate, rest, restful

Hola como están? estoy armando un pequeño proyecto api rest ful y al usar una sola tabla sin relaciones funciona bien, ahora si le agrego mas tablas y relaciones me falla la obtencion del json.
Consiguracion

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "ar.com.clothes")
public class AppConfig {

}
```

Hibernate

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "ar.com.clothes.configuration" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "ar.com.clothes.model" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
     }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        return properties;        
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
       HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
       txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
       return txManager;
    }
}
```

Mi pom

```
<properties>
        <spring.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <security.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</security.version>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>2.4.1</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons DBCP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring ORM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>ClothesApi</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Saque jackson por que aun no lo se usar.
y aqui mi controller:

```
@RestController
public class UsuarioController {

    @Autowired
    UsuarioService usuarioService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getAllUsuarios", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public List<Usuario> getAllUsuarios() {

        List<Usuario> listUsuarios = usuarioService.findAllUsuarios();
        return listUsuarios;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getUsuario/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public Usuario getUsuarioById(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        return usuarioService.findById(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addUsuario", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public void addUsuario(@RequestBody Usuario usuario) {
        usuarioService.saveUsuario(usuario);

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/updateUsuario", method = RequestMethod.PUT, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public void updateUsuario(@RequestBody Usuario usuario) {
        usuarioService.updateUsuario(usuario);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteUsuario/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public void deleteUsuario(@PathVariable("id") int usuarioId) {
        usuarioService.deleteUsuarioById(usuarioId);
    }

    // lukas

    @RequestMapping(path = "/listaUsuarios", method = { RequestMethod.GET }, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody List<Usuario> listUsuario() {
        return this.usuarioService.findAllUsuarios();
    }
}
```

al ejecutar obtengo esto en el log.

```
2017-03-03 14:39:03 [DEBUG] [org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter.toString(EntityPrinter.java:114)] Listing entities:

2017-03-03 14:39:03 [DEBUG] [org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter.toString(EntityPrinter.java:121)] ar.com.clothes.model.Empresa{encargos=<uninitialized>, domicilio=Necochea 465, idEmpresa=1, clienteses=<uninitialized>, telefono=4226288, usuarios=[ar.com.clothes.model.Usuario#1], email=jlopezjuy@gmail.com, nombreEmpresa=Nicole Boutique}

2017-03-03 14:39:03 [DEBUG] [org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter.toString(EntityPrinter.java:121)] ar.com.clothes.model.Usuario{password=e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e, nombreApellido=Juan Manuel Lopez, idUsuario=1, nombreUsuario=jlopez, empresa=ar.com.clothes.model.Empresa#1}

2017-03-03 14:39:03 [DEBUG] [org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter.toString(EntityPrinter.java:121)] ar.com.clothes.model.Empresa{encargos=<uninitialized>, domicilio=Necochea 345, idEmpresa=2, clienteses=<uninitialized>, telefono=4236241, usuarios=[ar.com.clothes.model.Usuario#2], email=compartiendolavida@gmail.com, nombreEmpresa=Jeniffer Cabrini}

2017-03-03 14:39:03 [DEBUG] [org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter.toString(EntityPrinter.java:121)] ar.com.clothes.model.Usuario{password=e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e, nombreApellido=Maria Sonia, idUsuario=2, nombreUsuario=msonia, empresa=ar.com.clothes.model.Empresa#2}

2017-03-03 14:39:03 [DEBUG] [org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.disconnect(SessionImpl.java:468)] Disconnecting session

2017-03-03 14:39:03 [DEBUG] [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.releaseConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:246)] Releasing JDBC connection

2017-03-03 14:39:03 [DEBUG] [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.releaseConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:264)] Released JDBC connection

2017-03-03 14:39:03 [DEBUG] [org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:759)] Initiating transaction commit

2017-03-03 14:39:03 [DEBUG] [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:580)] Committing Hibernate transaction on Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@7c4387d4 updates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@67777290 deletions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@43880303 orphanRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@3b0fe53a collectionCreations=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@5b12a8a8 collectionRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@72da2a8 collectionUpdates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@43e2955 collectionQueuedOps=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@40dc2add unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])]

2017-03-03 14:39:03 [DEBUG] [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)] committing

2017-03-03 14:39:03 [DEBUG] [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:113)] committed JDBC Connection

2017-03-03 14:39:03 [DEBUG] [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.releaseManagedConnection(JdbcTransaction.java:126)] re-enabling autocommit

2017-03-03 14:39:03 [DEBUG] [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCleanupAfterCompletion(HibernateTransactionManager.java:669)] Closing Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@7c4387d4 updates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@67777290 deletions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@43880303 orphanRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@3b0fe53a collectionCreations=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@5b12a8a8 collectionRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@72da2a8 collectionUpdates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@43e2955 collectionQueuedOps=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@40dc2add unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] after transaction

2017-03-03 14:39:03 [DEBUG] [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.releaseConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:246)] Releasing JDBC connection

2017-03-03 14:39:03 [DEBUG] [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.releaseConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:264)] Released JDBC connection

2017-03-03 14:39:03 [DEBUG] [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:131)] Resolving exception from handler [public java.util.List<ar.com.clothes.model.Usuario> ar.com.clothes.web.UsuarioController.listUsuario()]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation

2017-03-03 14:39:03 [DEBUG] [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:131)] Resolving exception from handler [public java.util.List<ar.com.clothes.model.Usuario> ar.com.clothes.web.UsuarioController.listUsuario()]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation

2017-03-03 14:39:03 [DEBUG] [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:131)] Resolving exception from handler [public java.util.List<ar.com.clothes.model.Usuario> ar.com.clothes.web.UsuarioController.listUsuario()]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation

2017-03-03 14:39:03 [WARN ] [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.logException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:186)] Handler execution resulted in exception: Could not find acceptable representation

2017-03-03 14:39:03 [DEBUG] [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1034)] Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling

2017-03-03 14:39:03 [DEBUG] [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1000)] Successfully completed request
```

Espero me puedan dar una mano, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas enganchar Spring con Hibernate con la siguiente dependencia:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

En la capa DAO es donde tienes que tener esa implementacion @Controller ---> @Service ----> DAO (@Repository)

Aqui tienes un ejemplo: 
http://www.journaldev.com/3531/spring-mvc-hibernate-mysql-integration-crud-example-tutorial

Comment: Pruebo apenas llegue a casa, gracias por responder.

Comment: Te ha funcionado?

Comment: Pues dame positivo ;-)

Comment: no me deja, me falta mas puntos de reputación.... apenas los consiga te pongo el positivo.

Answer (score 0):

Si funciono correctamente con esa dependencia, aparte le agregue el @Colum(name = "idCliente") y @Colum(name = "idEmpresa"), y salio bien, ahora sigo avanzando, gracias por responder.